# Rails 3 how to force response type when request type is */*

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mime-types, respond-to

I have a `before_filter` which wants to default the response type depending on various aspects of the request and parameters. E.g.,

```
request.format = ( params.format ||= 'html' ) if ...    # an HTML-only request/client
request.format = ( params.format ||= 'json' ) if request.xhr?
```

the idea being that the `respond_to do |format|; format.html { ... }; format.json { ... }` would then render appropriately according to the client conditions. Some of the clients are coming in as type `*/*` (presumably this is `request.content_type` ?) and I want to force these to be HTML responses. Doesn't seem to be working however. What is a clean way to do this, and without setting a default type for each route ?   I.e. I just want to poke the response type into the request so that `respond_to` will switch on it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.format=` should be an object of type `MIME::Type`.

So you'd have to do something like `request.format = MIME::Types.type_for('html').first`

Comment: thx, however this seems to have the "magic" side-effect of also changing `params.format`.    without digging into the source, I just set it to a `StringEnquirer` so that e.g.  `.html?` works but also `.json?` etc.